# Get list of strings between < >

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of mails that are between `'<'`, `'>'`
eg. `'<mail1@test.com>, <mail2@test.com>'`.

I need to return a list with the mails: `['mail1@test.com', 'mail2@test.com']`

Tried

```
re.search('<(.*)>', '<mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com>').group(0)
```

But I get the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to return the matches as a list, and you need to make your `.*` not greedy by appending a question-mark. See the section on `*?` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
re.findall('<(.*?)>', '<mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com>')
# ['mail1@test.com', 'mail2@test.com']
```

Note that if your input string is always formatted like the example you gave, you can achieve the same thing with:

```
test_string = '<mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com>'
[s[1:-1] for s in test_string.split()]
# ['mail1@test.com', 'mail2@test.com']
```

This just splits on the whitespace between emails, and then takes only the characters between the first and last in each email, tossing out the `'<'` and `'>'`.

Regex is great, but it's often more trouble than it's worth for simpler manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

There are two things that should be amended for this to work.

Instead of using `re.search()`, use `re.findall()`

```py
>>> re.findall('<(.*)>', '<mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com>')
['mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com']
```

`re.search()` will just find one match while `re.findall()` will search for all matches.

Your regular expression is 'greedy', add a question mark to the regular expression to fix that.

```py
>>> re.findall('<(.*?)>', '<mail1@test.com> <mail2@test.com>')
['mail1@test.com', 'mail2@test.com']
```

A greedy expression will try to swallow as much text as possible. This is not what you want in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bothering with regular expressions you can create a list of each address and then remove the angle brackets:

```
[x.replace('<', '').replace('>', '') for x in '<mail1@test.com>, <mail2@test.com>'.split(', ')]
```